# Remote username Django

Tags: django, django-views

I need to get remote username in django. I mean the username logged into windows.
Like getting logged in username in views.py user=request.user. Is there any command to get remote username?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What's exactly the scenario? Are you using OAuth with a 3rd party authentication provider and asking for the username there? What authentication method are you using?

Comment: i am using RemoteUserMiddleware. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/auth-remote-user/

Comment: for registered users i am getting their username by using user=request.user. But for non registered users am giving authentication using remoteusermiddleware.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the username using `username = request.META.get('REMOTE_USER')`. As per documentation, the username is extracted from Header with key `REMOTE_USER`(unless you override it with custom middleware). Please see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user)  for more details.